# Libcurl - проверить curl_easy дескриптор на актуальность

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

Подскажите пожалуйста, позволяет ли Libcurl, как то проверить дескриптор Curl_easy - закрыт он или нет ?

То есть могу ли я для данного дескриптора вызвать curl_easy_perform() или Curl_multi_handle() - чтобы не произошло ошибки ?

Нашел только вот такое очень краткое и туманное упоминание:
https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_cleanup.html

> Иногда вы можете получить обратный вызов выполнения или обратный вызов
> заголовка из curl_easy_cleanup (если ранее был установлен для
> дескриптора с помощью curl_easy_setopt ).

Но, что это за обратный вызов, с помощью какой опции он устанавливается - как то не раскрывается.

Comment: Ни разу не юзал эту либу, но подозреваю, что  для проверки можно попробовать вызвать [curl_easy_getinfo](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html) (прошелся по See Also в вашей ссылке)

Comment: От открыт до вызова `curl_easy_cleanup`. А проверить это никак нельзя. Наоборот, задача програмиста - обеспечить, чтобы действия всегда происходили только с валидными дескрипторами.